# Convert a number into a string and only keep two decimals in calc

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to have the code below calculate and have a final value that only shows two decimals for the id 'eqauls'.

I tried toFixed function but it doesn't work...

```
$('input').keyup(function(){ 
    var firstValue  = Number($('#box1').val());   
    var secondValue = Number($('#box2').val()); 
    var thirdValue = Number($('#box3').val());
    var forthValue = Number($('#box3').val());
    var fifthValue = Number($('#boxA'));
    document.getElementById('boxB').value = document.getElementById('answer').value

    document.getElementById('result').value = firstValue * secondValue;
    document.getElementById('answer').value = document.getElementById('result').value * forthValue;
    document.getElementById('equals').value = document.getElementById('boxA').value / document.getElementById('answer').value

});
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of the values in boxA and answer? Also, value returns the text value in String form. Have you considered converting it to an Integer and then performing the calculation?

Comment: just some friendly advise, If you use jQuery to get the element by Id, it would make sense to use jQuery everywhere instead of  document.getElementById.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('equals').value = parseFloat(document.getElementById('boxA').value / document.getElementById('answer').value).toFixed(2)
```

To use `.toFixed` you need to use parseFloat first to ensure it is a float you are working with.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wxm8c7uf/)

Comment: happy to help you with something but won't charge for it if it is that quick.

Comment: go to my website (www.klu.io) and send me a message through contact form. Unless they changed it there is no DM / PM on SO

Comment: logging off now bud, will wait for your message

Comment: I responded via email to your email but got no response, I can look at it tomorrow for you, out the rest of today.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `parseInt(Number($('#box1').val())).toFixed(2)` it will fixed value into two digit format

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toString()` to convert `number` into `string` and `toFixed()` method to set exact two decimal point .

```
document.getElementById('equals').value = (document.getElementById('boxA').value / document.getElementById('answer').value).toFixed(2).toString();
```

Here the output of `typeof document.getElementById('equals').value` will be `string`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are are trying to calculate exactly, but this is one way to do it.

```js
$('input').keyup(function() {

  var firstValue = parseFloat($('#box1').val());
  var secondValue = parseFloat($('#box2').val());
  
  var thirdValue = parseFloat($('#box3').val());
  var forthValue = parseFloat($('#box3').val());
  
  var fifthValue = parseFloat($('#boxA').val());
  
  // get the result
  $('#result').val(firstValue * secondValue);
  
  // get the answer
  $('#answer').val($('#result').val() * forthValue);
  
  // set the boxB value
  $('#boxB').val($('#answer').val());
  
  // get equals and then set to a fixed 2 decimals places
  var equals = $('#boxA').val() / $('#answer').val();
  $('#equals').val(equals.toFixed(2));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

BOX 1<input id="box1" type="number"><br>
BOX 2<input id="box2" type="number"><br>
BOX 3<input id="box3" type="number"><br>
<br>
BOX A<input id="boxA" type="number"><br>
BOX B<input id="boxB" type="number"><br>
<br>
RESULT<input id="result" type="number"><br>
ANSWER<input id="answer" type="number"><br>
EQUALS<input id="equals" type="number"><br>
```